What is the connection between 'ἐκληρώθημεν προορισθέντες' in Ephesians 1:11
With the help of Logos, interlinars, and commentaries I am trying to get to the initial meaning of bible verses.
Ephesians 1:11:

en hō kai eklērōthēmen prooristhentes kata prothesin tou ta panta energountos kata tēn boulēn tou thelēmatos autou,

Which is translated in the Logos Lexham Bible as:

in whom also we were chosen, having been predestined according to the purpose of the One who works all things according to the counsel of his will,

The meaning of 'ἐκληρώθημεν' (eklērōthēmen) is a bit vague and differs between translations: we were chosen (by lot) or we obtained/were made an inheritance.
The meaning of 'προορισθέντες'(prooristhentes) is about predetermine /predestinate etc.
What is the connection between those two words?
In most translations, there is a comma in between, but I do not see that in the Greek text.
Can it be that it could mean something like:

we were predetermined/predestined to be chosen

or

we were predetermined/predestined to be made (/obtain) an inheritance

So that 'prooristhentes' says something about the previous 'eklērōthēmen'?
I did look at the other questions/answers about this verse, such as:

In Ephesians 1:11 how should προορισθέντες (IE: "predestined") be translated?
What Paul meant by "inheritance" in Eph 1:11-14: WHAT exactly it is and WHEN do we receive it?
In Ephesians 1:10, to what or whom does «τὰ πάντα...τὰ...ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς» refer?


In Eph 1:11 "Inheritance" and "predestined"  occur "in him".
Ephesians 1:4

"he chose us [to be] in him before the foundation of the world,"

My bracket. Being  "in him"  occurs as he  "he works all things".
"eklerothemen" a passive verb. Something done to us by the one who not only predestines the end but also the means, otherwise the end is uncertain and not predestinated.
Helps Word-studies

"The Greek text literally reads, 'In whom [Christ], indeed we are lot-cast [kleroo] having already been pre-horizoned [aorist participle] according to [divine] purpose, of the one energising all things according to the counsel [boule]  arising from his will [thelema]."

Something done to us-"we are lot-cast" because "pre-horizoned".
Examples of proorizo: In Romans 8:29 and in Ephesians 1:5 in ESV, KJB and NASB 1977 it is always "predestined".

According to BDAG, the verb προορίζω (proorizó) simply means,

decide upon beforehand, predetermine, eg, Rom 8:29, 30, Acts 4:28, 1 Cor 2:7, Eph 1:5, 11.

Note that it does NOT mean, "predestine".  The difference is quite important (and controversial) - if something is decided upon beforehand, does not mean it must occur.
By contrary example, there are numerous instances where God wants and intends something but people are disobedient.  God wants all people to be doers of His will, but some do not, for example:

The “wilderness generation” of Israelites that God called out of Egypt perished in the desert because, despite being called, turned their backs on God and refused to trust in God by believing the majority spy report.
At the end of the wilderness wandering, Joshua begged the people to choose to serve God, Josh 24:15, 22.  See also Deut 30:19, Judg 5:8, Job 34:4, 33, 21, Ps 119:173, Prov 1:29, 3:31, Isa 7:15, 16, 56:4, 65:12, 66:3, Jer 8:3.
King Saul who was a statesman and prophet called by God (1 Sam 10:11, 12, 19:24), yet was ultimately lost when he consulted demons for advice and then committed suicide.
Ps 69:28 contains a plea for David’s enemies to be blotted out of the book of life!
Eze 18:21-28 also teaches that the wicked can reform and be saved, and the righteous can apostatize and be lost.  Both situations are incompatible with Calvinism’s view of salvation and humanity.
Rom 11:17-21 discusses the warning that people who had been grafted into the “olive tree” of the Christian community could be broken off if they were unfaithful.
1 Cor 9:27 Paul says he disciplines his body to keep it under control so that after preaching to others he does not become a castaway/disqualified.  That is, Paul believed that it was possible that he could lose his way and become lost.
1 Tim 6:10, For the love of money is the root of all kinds of evils.  It is through this craving that some have wandered away from the faith and pierced themselves with many pangs.
Similarly, Heb 6:4-6 also teaches that some “who have once been enlightened, who have tasted the heavenly gift, who have shared in the Holy Spirit…” can fall away.
Heb 10:19-35 contains an extended passage on enduring.  It contains some real gems about the possibility of losing one’s faith and confidence such as:


V26: If we(!) deliberately keep on sinning after receiving the knowledge of the truth, no sacrifice for sins is left




V29: How much more severely do you think someone deserves to be punished who has trampled the Son of God underfoot, who has treated as an unholy thing the blood of the covenant that sanctified them and who has insulted the Spirit of grace.  This verse clearly shows that it is possible to be sanctified and subsequently lost.




V35: Therefore, do not throw away your confidence which has a great reward.




V36: You need to persevere so that when you have done the will of God you will receive what he has promised.




Heb 13:9, “Do not be led away by diverse and strange teachings, for it is good for the heart to be strengthened by grace …”


2 Peter 1:10, “make your calling and election sure”.  This clearly allows for the possibility of losing one’s election.
2 Peter 2:21, “It would have been better for them not to have known the way of righteousness, than to have known it and then to turn their backs on the sacred command that was passed on to them.”
2 Peter 3:17 contains a very stern and sobering warning to be on guard that we do not fall from our secure position.  Verse 14 contains a similar warning.
1 Cor 10:12 also contains a stern warning from Paul, “If you think you are standing firm, be careful that you don’t fall.”
Gal 6:9 says, “Let us not become weary in doing good, for at the proper time we will reap a harvest if we do not give up.”

All these illustrate the single most important point about salvation and what God's will is - what He predetermined - all people to be saved (but many will not be saved):

1 Tim 2:3, 4, “For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth.”
1 Tim 2:6, “[Jesus Christ] gave Himself as a ransom for all people.”
Titus 2:11, “For the grace of God appeared bringing salvation to all people.”
Heb 2:9, “But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels, now crowned with glory and honor because he suffered death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone.”
2 Peter 3:9, “The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness.  He is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance.”
1 John 2:2, “He Himself [Jesus] is the propitiation for our sins, and not for ours [Christians to whom John writes] only but also for the whole world.”

Ephesians 1:5, 11
Thus, the OP's verse simply reads thus:

Eph 1:11 - in Him, in whom also we have obtained an inheritance,
having been predetermined according to the purpose of the One working
all things according to the counsel of His will

Thus, God calls all people to Himself (see above verses) but only some respond and accept the working of divine grace in their lives.

Sorry for my mistake. Predestined or predetermined is not an issue for me. I am fine with both. Thanks for your explanation, that helps a lot especially since I am Dutch and English is not my native language.
But still my question is really about: is there a connection between the two words.

@flexJoly - OK, so now you have changed the scope of the question significantly!!

I am sorry that I was not clear! This was my question from the beginning. Sorry for the confusion.
